# Issue in showing the grid table in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created the new module in magento admin but when I am trying to add the grid table it is showing empty.Please anyone suggest me.

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/Block/Adminhtml/Calendar.php

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: nilesh.tighare
  * Date: 9/29/2015
  * Time: 11:56 AM
*/
  class Labwise_Calendar_Block_Adminhtml_Calendar extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
public function __construct()
{

    $this->_controller = "adminhtml_calendar";
    $this->_blockGroup = "labwise_calendar";
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Item Manager");
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Add Item");
    parent::__construct();
}
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    //die('I am here');
    $this->setChild( 'grid',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' .     $this->_controller . '_grid',
            $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
}
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/Block/Adminhtml/Calendar/Edit.php

```
 <?php

/**
* Created by PhpStorm.
* User: nilesh.tighare
* Date: 9/29/2015
* Time: 11:44 AM
*/
class Labwise_Calendar_Block_Adminhtml_Calendar_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_objectId = "id";
    $this->_blockGroup = "labwise_calendar";
    $this->_controller = "adminhtml_calendar";

    $this->_updateButton("save", "label",
        Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Save Item"));
    $this->_updateButton("delete", "label",
        Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Delete Item"));
}

public function getHeaderText()
{
    if (Mage::registry("calendar_data") &&
        Mage::registry("calendar_data")->getId()) {
        return Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Edit Item '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry("calendar_data")->getTitle()));
    } else {
        return Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Add Item");
    }
}
}
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/Block/Adminhtml/Calendar/Grid.php

```
 <?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: nilesh.tighare
 * Date: 9/28/2015
 * Time: 4:55 PM
*/
  class Labwise_Calendar_Block_Adminhtml_Calendar_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
/**
 * Define grid properties
 *
 */
public function __construct()
{
    die('I am here');
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('calendarGrid');
    // This is the primary key of the database
    $this->setDefaultSort("id");
    $this->setDefaultDir("DESC");
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}
/**
 * Prepare table columns
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('labwise_calendar')->__('Id'),
        'index'     => 'id',
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '50px',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('gender', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('labwise_calendar')->__('Gender'),
        'index'     => 'gender',
        'align' => 'left',
        'width' => '120px',
        'type' => 'options',
        'options' => array(
            'M' => 'Male',
            'F' => 'Female',
        ),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('height', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('labwise_calendar')->__('Height'),
        'index'     => 'height',
        'width' => '120px',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('weight', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('labwise_calendar')->__('Weight'),
        'index'     => 'weight',
        'width' => '120px',
    ));

    return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('labwise_calendar/calendar_collection');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
}

public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl("*/*/edit", array("id" => $row->getId()));
}
}
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/Block/Adminhtml/Calendar/Edit/Form.php

```
 <?php

 /**
  * Created by PhpStorm.
  * User: nilesh.tighare
  * Date: 9/29/2015
  * Time: 12:25 PM
 */
  class Labwise_Calendar_Block_Adminhtml_Calendar_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
  {
   protected function _prepareForm()
   {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
            'method' => 'post',
        )
    );

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
 }
 }
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/Block/Adminhtml/Calendar/Edit/Tabs.php

```
 <?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: nilesh.tighare
 * Date: 9/29/2015
 * Time: 12:27 PM
 */
 class Labwise_Calendar_Block_Adminhtml_Calendar_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
  public function __construct()
   {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId("calendar_tabs");
    $this->setDestElementId("edit_form");
    $this->setTitle(Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Calendar Information"));
  }

  protected function _beforeToHtml()
  {
    $this->addTab("form_section", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Item Information"),
        "title" => Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Item Information"),
        "content" => $this->getLayout()->createBlock("labwise_calendar/adminhtml_calendar_edit_tab_form")->toHtml(),
    ));

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
}
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/Block/Adminhtml/Calendar/Edit/Tab/Form.php

```
<?php

/**
  * Created by PhpStorm.
  * User: nilesh.tighare
  * Date: 9/29/2015
  * Time: 12:29 PM
 */
      class Labwise_Calendar_Block_Adminhtml_Calendar_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
  {
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
      $this->setForm($form);
      $fieldset = $form->addFieldset("calendar_form", array("legend" => Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Item Information")));

    /*$fieldset->addField("age", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Age"),
        "class" => "required-entry",
        "required" => true,
        "name" => "age",
    ));*/

    $fieldset->addField("gender", "select", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Gender"),
        "name" => "gender",
        "values" => array(
            array(
                "value" => 'M',
                "label" => Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Male"),
            ),
            array(
                "value" => 'F',
                "label" => Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Female"),
            ),
        ),
    ));

    $fieldset->addField("height", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Height"),
        "class" => "required-entry",
        "required" => true,
        "name" => "height",
    ));

    $fieldset->addField("weight", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Weight"),
        "class" => "required-entry",
        "required" => true,
        "name" => "weight",
    ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getCalendarData()) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getCalendarData());
        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setCalendarData(null);
    } elseif (Mage::registry("calendar_data")) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry("calendar_data")->getData());
    }
    return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
 }
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/controllers/Adminhtml/CalendarController.php

```
  <?php

   /**
    * Created by PhpStorm.
    * User: nilesh.tighare
    * Date: 9/28/2015
    * Time: 5:28 PM
    */
    class Labwise_Calendar_Adminhtml_CalendarController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
   {
      protected function _initAction()
      {
       $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu("calendar/items")
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Items Manager"),
            Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item Manager")
        );
    return $this;
   }

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_initAction()->renderLayout();
}

public function editAction()
{
    $calendarId = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
    $calendarModel = Mage::getModel("labwise_calendar/calendar")->load($calendarId);

    if ($calendarModel->getId() || $calendarModel == 0) {
        Mage::register("calendar_data", $calendarModel);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu("calendar");

        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item Manager"),
            Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item Manager"));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item News"),
            Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item News"));

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('labwise_calendar/adminhtml_calendar_edit'))
            ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('labwise_calendar/adminhtml_calendar_edit_tabs'));

        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError(
            Mage::helper("labwise_calendar")->__("Item does not exist")
        );
        $this->_redirect("*/*/");
    }
}

public function newAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu("calendar");

    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item Manager"),
        Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item Manager"));
    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item News"),
        Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item News"));

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('labwise_calendar/adminhtml_calendar_edit'))
        ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('labwise_calendar/adminhtml_calendar_edit_tabs'));

    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function saveAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        try {
            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $calendarModel = Mage::getModel("labwise_calendar/calendar");

            $calendarModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
                ->setHeight($postData["height"])
                ->setWeight($postData["weight"])
                ->setGender($postData["gender"])
                ->save();

            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item was successfully saved")
            );
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setNewsData(false);

            $this->_redirect("*/*/");
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setNewsData(
                $this->getRequest()->getPost()
            );
            $this->_redirect("*/*/edit",
                array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
            );
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect("*/*/");
}

public function deleteAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("id") > 0) {
        try {
            $newsModel = Mage::getModel("labwise_calendar/calendar");

            $newsModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))->delete();

            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Item was successfully deleted")
            );
            $this->_redirect("*/*/");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect("*/*/edit",
                array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
            );
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect("*/*/");
  }
}
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Labwise_Calendar>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Labwise_Calendar>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <labwise_calendar>
            <class>Labwise_Calendar_Block</class>
        </labwise_calendar>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <labwise_calendar>
            <class>Labwise_Calendar_Helper</class>
        </labwise_calendar>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <labwise_calendar>
            <class>Labwise_Calendar_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>labwise_calendar_resource</resourceModel>
        </labwise_calendar>
        <labwise_calendar_resource>
            <class>Labwise_Calendar_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <calendar>
                    <table>mg_childgrowth</table>
                </calendar>
            </entities>
        </labwise_calendar_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <labwise_calendar_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Labwise_Calendar</module>
            </setup>
        </labwise_calendar_setup>
        <labwise_calendar_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </labwise_calendar_write>
        <labwise_calendar_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </labwise_calendar_read>
    </resources>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <labwisecalendar>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Labwise_Calendar</module>
                <frontName>adminlabwisecalendar</frontName>
            </args>
        </labwisecalendar>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <report>
                        <children>
                            <calendar translate="title" module="labwise_calendar">
                                <title>Calendar</title>
                            </calendar>
                        </children>
                    </report>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <labwisecalendar>
                <file>labwise/calendar.xml</file>
            </labwisecalendar>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
 </config>
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <report>
        <children>
            <calendar translate="title" module="labwise_calendar">
                <title>Caledar</title>
                <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                <action>adminlabwisecalendar/adminhtml_calendar</action>
            </calendar>
        </children>
    </report>
</menu>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/Helper/Data.php

```
 <?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: nilesh.tighare
 * Date: 9/28/2015
 * Time: 5:21 PM
 */
class Labwise_Calendar_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/Model/Calendar.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: nilesh.tighare
 * Date: 9/28/2015
 * Time: 4:33 PM
 */
 class Labwise_Calendar_Model_Calendar extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 {
    protected function _construct()
    {
    $this->_init('labwise_calendar/calendar');
    }
 }
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/Model/Resource/Calendar.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: nilesh.tighare
 * Date: 9/28/2015
 * Time: 4:36 PM
*/
 class Labwise_Calendar_Model_Resource_Calendar extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
/**
 * Initialize resource
 *
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('labwise_calendar/calendar', 'id');
}
 }
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/Model/Resource/Calendar/Collection.php

```
 <?php

 /**
  * Created by PhpStorm.
  * User: nilesh.tighare
  * Date: 9/28/2015
  * Time: 4:39 PM
  */
  class Labwise_Calendar_Model_Resource_Calendar_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
 {
  /**
  * Initialize collection
   *
  */
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('labwise_calendar/calendar');
}
}
```

app/code/local/Labwise/Calendar/sql/labwise_calendar_setup/install-1.0.0.php

```
 <?php
 /**
  * Created by PhpStorm.
  * User: nilesh.tighare
  * Date: 9/28/2015
  * Time: 4:12 PM
  */
   $installer = $this;
   $installer->startSetup();
   $installer->run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mg_childgrowth(
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   gender varchar(60) NOT NULL,
   height varchar(60) NOT NULL,
   weight varchar(60) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
   );");

 $installer->endSetup();
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/default/layout/labwise/calendar.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
 <labwisecalendar_adminhtml_calendar_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="labwise_calendar/adminhtml_calendar"    name="calendar" />
      </reference>
</labwisecalendar_adminhtml_calendar_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: have you enabled developer mode to see errors ??

Comment: Yes,But it is not showing any errors when I write die("I am here") in block and grid it is printing.But it not showing any grid table.

Comment: con you send me your extension on my email arunendra.gct@gmail.com

Comment: I sent a mail of my module.Please check it.

Comment: @Arunendra have you checked my mail.Please reply me.

Comment: I am checking it on my local machine

Comment: Ok.Please ping me if it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29698/discussion-between-arunendra-and-mouni).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your sql code file:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$sql=<<<SQLTEXT
create table if not exists mg_childgrowth(id int not null auto_increment, gender varchar(100),height varchar(60),weight varchar(60), primary key(id));
    insert into mg_childgrowth values('1','M','23','5.5');
    insert into mg_childgrowth values('2','F','22','6.5');

SQLTEXT;

$installer->run($sql);
$installer->endSetup();
```